# how can I get a sum of every month before its?

Tags: mysql

I hava a MySQL table like the following.

```
| id | money | date |
| ---- | ---- | ----|
| 1 | 100 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 150 | 2020-01-15 |
| 3 | 70 | 2020-02-01 |
| 4 | 80 | 2020-02-06 |
| 5 | 100 | 2020-03-02 |
| 6 | 100 | 2020-03-16 |
| 7 | 200 | 2020-04-08 |
```

And I want to get the result like this

```
| year-month | sumMoney |
| ---- | ---- |
| 2020-01 | 250 |
| 2020-02 | 400 |
| 2020-03 | 600 |
| 2020-04 | 800 |
```

How to write sql ?

Comment: What MySQL version you have. You should to use window functions, introduced since MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySQL 8.0, where introduced window function, you can use next query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') mnth,
  SUM(money) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') ) AS sumMoney
FROM test;
```

Test query [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=abf9c03388a6d14418269784d6703eeb&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

**Result:**

```
yearmonth | sumMoney
----------+---------
2020-01   |      250
2020-02   |      400
2020-03   |      600
2020-04   |      800
```

Solution for oldest MySQL versions:

```
select 
    cur.mn, 
    (ifnull(sum(prev.prev_sum),0) + money) as rolling_sum 
from (
    select sum(money) money, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')  mn
    from test
    group by DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
) cur
left join (
    select sum(money) prev_sum, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')  prev_mn
    from test
    group by DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
) prev on prev.prev_mn < cur.mn
group by cur.mn
order by mn;
```

[run PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=d588b6b1b06c1968c94b88dcafb51015&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: But if I am using mysql56 , it does not work,any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate by year and month using `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT
    yearmonth,
    SUM(sumMoney) OVER (ORDER BY yearmonth) AS sumMoney
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS yearmonth, SUM(money) AS sumMoney
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
) t
ORDER BY
    yearmonth;
```

Comment: It's not an rolling sum. This query not returns desired result

Comment: I fixed it.  Sorry, I didn't check the data very closely.

Comment: this query doesn't run without errors (3 currently)

Comment: @Lance Are you using MySQL 5.7?  Don't.  Please upgrade to 8+ if you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum the column and then group by the year and month.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m") AS, 'year-month' SUM(money) AS 'sumMoney' 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Comment: This doesn't give a rolling sum, which is what the OP wants.  It may run without error, but the output is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen; I didn't see the rolling sum requirement in the question.